# Why are computer displays Class I devices but TVs Class II?

Tags: grounding, iec

I was wondering why all computer displays I know are Class I devices, or at least come with a Schuko plug, while all TVs I know are double insulated Class II devices?

I understand it might have something to do with the user being closer to a computer display (although you should not touch your screen anyways or it will get greasy fingers all over it!)
But the computer display casings I know are just made out of plastic so hooking it up to earth really would not make much difference, or am I wrong?

Comment: Monitors are expected to be connected to other devices that aren’t double insulated.

Comment: The case of wall mounts where the monitor or TV is being connected to a not-otherwise grounded exposed metal frame with metal threaded inserts that require high strength is probably an example of a reason, although I think I've seen 2 prong wall mount TVs, so perhaps I'm wrong or perhaps the inserts can be insulated as an alternative.

Comment: There are also monitors without Schuko plug so they are ungrounded, and there are also TVs with grounded Schuko plug. At least I find a metal frame TVs with ungrounded plugs horrible to work with, as touching them gives tingles and they need to be unplugged first before connecting to other equipment to prevent damage.

Comment: But _most_ TVs have plastic frames, the ones with metal frames are mostly found in professional settings.
For the wall mounts: I've just wall mounted my TV last weekend, I don't think wall mounting would not be the reason. I think @Kartman has the best explanation; "Desktop" PCs are big iron boxes, those are not double insulated, that might be the reason. All this while DVD Players and so on are typically double isolated (PS3 is not!)

Also, my new 4K Samsung screen is double isolated, and my old Philips TV also had DVI & VGA inputs. Maybe more than anything else, the best reason is 'habit'